# trying to display a list of data in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to display a list of data in a WPF data grid because a textblock just threw the data together without any type of formatting (this is me hoping that formatting of this data is done for me).

This is the code behind

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e == null)
            return;

        if (e.CmsData != null)
        {
            List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
            {
                mylist.Add(item.AgName);
                mylist.Add(item.AuxReasonDescription);
            }
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
            {
                this.datagrid.ItemsSource = mylist;
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML I'm using to populate the data grid

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="178.201">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=mylist, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   x:Name="datagrid" Background="{x:Null}" Loaded="textBlock_Loaded"/>
</Grid>
```

this is the agents.cs file that has variables i'm trying to pull into my data grid just incase it is needed.

```
public class Agent : IEquatable<Agent>
{
    public int Extension { get; set; }
    public int WorkModeDirection { get; set; }
    public string WorkModeDirectionDescription { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan AgTime { get; set; }
    public int AuxReason { get; set; }
    public string AuxReasonDescription { get; set; }
    public int DaInQueue { get; set; }
    public int WorkSkill { get; set; }
    public int OnHold { get; set; }
    public int Acd { get; set; }
    public String LoginId { get; set; }
    public string AgName { get; set; }
    public int EId { get; set; }
    public int Preference { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeUpdated { get; set; }
    public int CmId { get; set; }
    #region Implementation of IEquatable<Agent>

    public bool Equals(Agent other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return (other.LoginId == LoginId & other.CmId == CmId);
    }

    #endregion

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Agent))
            return false;

        return Equals((Agent)obj);
    }

    //public override int GetHashCode()
    //{
    //    return LoginId;
    //}
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        string combinedNumber = "" + CmId + LoginId;
        int hash = Convert.ToInt32(combinedNumber);
        return hash;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Agent left, Agent right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Agent left, Agent right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return " Ag: [Ext:" + Extension + " login:" + LoginId + " AgName:" + AgName + " CmId:" + CmId + "]";
    }
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return LoginId != null;
    }
}
```

This is what is currently being displayed...of which contains no information that I am telling it to print out and I have no idea where the numbers are coming from.
[image]

Comment: you are trying to bind a datagrid to a list of string. It doesn't make sense. Are you trying to show one Agent object per line?

Comment: Yes I'd like the first column to be agent names, the second column to be agentauxdescription and so on and so forth for other available variables I try to add.  I've already tried this with a textblock and a richtextblock and failed miserably. a co-worker advised I try this.

Comment: Instead make your items as an object and add it to the observable collection and bind it with your datagrid itemsource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to a `List<Agent>`:

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e == null)
            return;

        if (e.CmsData != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
            {
                this.datagrid.ItemsSource = e.CmsData.Agents.ToList();
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

...and define a column for each property of the `Agent` class that you want to display in the `DataGrid` in your XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      x:Name="datagrid" Background="{x:Null}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="AgName" Binding="{Binding AgName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="AuxReasonDescription" Binding="{Binding AuxReasonDescription}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: this is working the best for me I believe but in the XAML you have posted in your answer doesn't appear to be correct after you changed the code behind. the datagrid is still binding to mylist even though mylist no longer exists in the code example. Is this correct? or in this case what should datagrid bind to?

Comment: Yes, you could get rid of the ItemsSource binding if you set the ItemsSource programmatically in the OnMessageReceived method. I edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the route I'm going to take. I'm having a lot of issues with this datagrid that I don't like so far but it displays the information in the best way compared to other options.  Can I ask if you were trying to accomplish this would you still use a datagrid or something else?

Comment: Trying to accomplish what? Display a tabular list of data? I would use a DataGrid if I wanted to be able to edit the data. Otherwise I would use a ListView.

Comment: if I wanted to try a listview to see how this looks would I do the databinding the same way as a datagrid? I do not plan on having this data editable by the user.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. There is an example of how to use a ListView available here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind your DataGrid to a list of strings which doesn't make sense at all. Every item in your list that you bind to a DataGrid, should represent a row in the grid.

Since you are trying to show a single Agent data on each row, you should bind to the list of agents directly.

Try this;

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e == null)
                    return;

                if (e.CmsData != null)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
                    {                        
                        this.datagrid.ItemsSource = e.CmsData.Agents;
                    }));                    
                    }
            }
```

But keep in mind, this will generate columns for every public property of the Agent object. To specify which columns to show check this answer from another SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6766462/1675709